# How do I add a new file to meteorpad ?

Tags: meteor

I want to add a file to client/compatibility for http://meteorpad.com/pad/qurmu4uvWf96Xzin2.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding files is a feature that is not yet supported.